# Show messages with different color with delay in same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtY38/1/) with two buttons, if I click on first button the message should should show in red color and if i click second button it should show green colored message. I want show both in the same div with delay

```
function showAlertBarMessages(type) {
  var msg = msgQueue[0];
  if (!$('#msg-sequentially').find(':visible').length) {
     var el = $('<div />').html(msg).addClass('msg').appendTo('#msg-sequentially');
    el.fadeIn(500).promise().done(function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
            $(this).remove();
            msgQueue.splice(0,1);
            if(msgQueue.length) showAlertBarMessages(type);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: detail your need more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/ZtY38/4/) is what you want

```js
var msgQueue = [];
//var timeout;

function addMessage(color){
  msgQueue.push({message: "Message number " + (i + 1), color: color});
    showAlertBarMessages();
    i++;
}
var i = 0;

function showAlertBarMessages() {
    var msg = msgQueue[0];
    if (!$('#msg-sequentially').find(':visible').length) {
         var el = $('<div />').html(msg.message).addClass('msg ' + msg.color).appendTo('#msg-sequentially');
        el.fadeIn(500).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                $(this).remove();
                msgQueue.splice(0,1);
                if(msgQueue.length) showAlertBarMessages();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.msg {
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
}
.blue{
  background: #00abff;
}
.red{
  background: #F00000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg-sequentially"></div>
<button id="add-msg" onclick="addMessage('red')">Add red message</button>
<button id="add-msg" onclick="addMessage('blue')">Add blue message</button>
```

EDIT: I edited your queue with an object array, containing each message and the relative color

```
msgQueue.push({message: "Message number " + (i + 1), color: color});
```

Comment: If i click the button while the message is still showing, The next message doesnt show any color.

Comment: Yes it fixed my issue. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you pls provide a fix to my new issue? Suppose if i have a third button and when i press the button it should show message in the same div removing the messages produced by other two buttons..?

Comment: You should consider that a new question since the original one was already fulfilled

Comment: This is the link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913005/show-messages-with-different-color-with-delay-in-same-div-and-stop-showing-messa

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the attribute `data`to store your required colors, and then push new object having the message text and color to your `msgQueue` array.

```js
var msgQueue = [];
//var timeout;

var i = 0;
$('.add-msg').click(function () {
    msgQueue.push({"message":"Message number " + (i + 1),"color":$(this).data("color")});
    showAlertBarMessages();
    i++;
});

function showAlertBarMessages() {
    var msg = msgQueue[0].message;
    var color=msgQueue[0].color;
    if (!$('#msg-sequentially').find(':visible').length) {
        var el = $('<div />').html(msg).addClass('msg').appendTo('#msg-sequentially');
        el.css("background-color",color);
        el.fadeIn(500).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                $(this).remove();
                msgQueue.splice(0,1);
                if(msgQueue.length) showAlertBarMessages();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.msg {
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg-sequentially"></div>
<button class="add-msg" data-color="red">Add next message red</button>
<button class="add-msg" data-color="green">Add next message green</button>
```