# Show messages with different color with delay in same div and stop showing message when click another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a new button in this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/ZtY38/4/). When i click on the new button it should stop the messages produced by other buttons and show a new message in the same div with yellow color text.

```
function showAlertBarMessages() {
var msg = msgQueue[0];
if (!$('#msg-sequentially').find(':visible').length) {
     var el = $('<div />').html(msg.message).addClass('msg ' + msg.color).appendTo('#msg-sequentially');
    el.fadeIn(500).promise().done(function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
            $(this).remove();
            msgQueue.splice(0,1);
            if(msgQueue.length) showAlertBarMessages();
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Be careful that the jQuery delay isn't cancelable (read https://api.jquery.com/delay/) so once you have called it, you can't abort it.

Comment: Use setTimeout/setInterval and clearTimeout/clearInterval